Performing posterior inference on the number of clusters in a Dirichlet Process Mixture (DPM) model
I'm using a DPM model to perform posterior inference on the number of clusters on some data I've created and for which the "true" number of clusters is known (3). In order to sample from the posterior distribution of the kernel parameters I'm using a Blocked Gibbs sampler, as described in  Bayesian Data Analysis by Gelman et al., on chapter 23.
The problem I've noticed is that my results are highly sensitive to the choice of 'truncation' of the stick-breaking construction, i.e. at which step of the construction I assign all the remaining probability mass to the last 'stick' and therefore cap the maximum number of possible clusters.
What seems to happen is that as I allow for more clusters, the empirical distribution of the number of clusters shifts to higher and higher values, as many of the clusters are occupied by very few (often 1) observation and a small number of clusters hold the majority of observations.
One way to try and fix this I've been testing is to consider not the distribution of all clusters, but just of those that clear a certain minimum number of observations, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a less arbitrary way of doing this.
